# Simplify $\frac{\prod \limits_{j=1}^{n}j}{\prod \limits_{i=p+1}^{n-1}i\cdot \prod \limits_{k=1}^{p}j}$?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm reading an introductory book in combinatorics, I've been asked to expand and simplify the following:

$$\frac{\prod_{j=1}^{n}j}{\prod_{i=p+1}^{n-1}i\cdot \prod_{k=1}^{p}k}$$

I've managed to do it until here:

$$\frac{n!}{\prod_{i=p+1}^{n-1}i\cdot p!}$$

But the remaining product bugs me. In the trial of understand it, I've tried to make the example in which $n=p=8$, then I'd get:

$$\prod_{i=p+1}^{n-1}i=\prod_{i=9}^{7}i=i\cdot(i-1)\cdot(i-2)$$

With this, I noticed that presuming $n=p$, this product would have that form, then:

$$\frac{n!}{i\cdot(i-1)\cdot(i-2)\cdot p!}=\frac{n!}{(a^3-3a^2-2a)\cdot p!}$$

I guess that perhaps this is what should be done, but from here I'm stuck. Can you help me?

Comment: I think there is a typo in the second line: the $k!$ should perhaps be $p!$. Same for the $j!$.

Comment: Note that having a term $\prod_{i=p+1}^{n-1}i$ implicitly implies that $n-1 \geq p+1$ which becomes $p\leq n-2$. Your example with $n=p=8$ is therefore not a good example to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{\prod_{j=1}^{n}j}{\prod_{i=p+1}^{n-1}i\cdot \prod_{k=1}^{p}k} = \frac{n!}{[(p+1)(p+2)...(n-1)][p!]} = \frac{n!}{(n-1)!}=n$$

Comment: I don't understand how $[(p+1)(p+2)...(n-1)][p!] =(n-1)!$ Can you expand a little on this part?

Comment: Well, let's take an example: $1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 5= (3!)\cdot 4 \cdot 5= 5!$. I used the same idea in my answer. We have $p!$ on one side, multiply it by $p+1$ and you get $(p+1)(p!)=(p+1)!$ and then you multiply that with $p+2$ to get $(p+2)!$ and so on. You keep doing this till the number $n-1$ to get $(n-1)!$. You need to remember that $n-1 \geq p+1$. :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I get it now. You explain it very well.

Comment: You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's two different ways:

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{\prod_{j=1}^{n}j}{\prod_{i=p+1}^{n-1}i\cdot \prod_{k=1}^{p}k}
&=\dfrac{\prod_{j=1}^{n}j}{\prod_{i=p+1}^{n-1}i}\dfrac{1}{ \prod_{k=1}^{p}k}\\
&=\dfrac{n\prod_{j=1}^{p}j}{1}\dfrac{1}{ \prod_{k=1}^{p}k}\\
&=\dfrac{n\prod_{j=1}^{p}j}{ \prod_{k=1}^{p}k}\\
&= n\\
\end{array}
$

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{\prod_{j=1}^{n}j}{\prod_{i=p+1}^{n-1}i\cdot \prod_{k=1}^{p}k}
&=\dfrac{\prod_{j=1}^{n}j}{\prod_{k=1}^{p}k}\dfrac{1}{\prod_{i=p+1}^{n-1}i }\\
&=\dfrac{\prod_{j=p+1}^{n}j}{1}\dfrac{1}{\prod_{i=p+1}^{n-1}i}\\
&=\dfrac{\prod_{j=p+1}^{n}j}{\prod_{i=p+1}^{n-1}i}\\
&= n\\
\end{array}
$